# How to restart a deleted worklist item process in K2 Blackpearl?

Tags: c#, k2

I have joined the k2underground forum but no one seems to be answering my queries. What I want to do now is to restart a process even after tagging it as deleted.

Is there a way to do that??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe once you actually delete a process instance it is not recoverable. You have the option to delete the log entries or not (so it will still show up on worklists etc as deleted) but I don't know of an "undelete and restore state" possibility.

You might want to look at the logic of why you need to delete and undelete. Instead of deleting maybe send the process to a "holding" activity, where it can easily be routed back into the flow (or actually deleted) at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about deleting a process definition?  or a process instance?

the previous commenter is correct re: process instances.  but you can always start another instance from the existing definition.

on the other hand, if you delete a process definition (using undocumented stored procs) you'll need to redeploy the definition before being able start another instance.